# Having a hard time positioning image behind Bootstrap navbar (Z-index)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, z-index, positioning

This is the navbar layout

```
<header id="navigation-bar" class="nav-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo-icon">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">How we work <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item2 active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item2 active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Account <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link nav-btn-link" href="#"><button class="nav-btn btn btn-outline-dark">View Plans</button><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
    </header>
```

bg-img1 is the image I'm trying to position behind navbar:

```
<section id="Heading">
    <img class="bg-img1" src="images/bg-pattern-intro-right-desktop.svg" alt="bg-pattern-left">
    <div class="container-1">
      <div class="heading-text">
```

I tried putting a header around the navbar and positioning the z-index but it doesnt seem to do it justice.

```
.nav-header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1%;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

and this is how I positioned my image:

```
.bg-img1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 40%;
  top: 3%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: May i ask where you are using the `section` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right but because you are giving `src` to your `img` attribute, as a result of which it will be treated as an image which will not be appearing behind  the `navbar` but in front.

Instead of giving `src` to your image, you can use `CSS background property` for your `img` attribute which will make the `img` appear behind the navbar. So no need of any `z-index`

```css
.bg-img1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590845947667-381579052389?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section id="Heading">
  <img class="bg-img1" alt="bg-pattern-left">
  <div class="container-1">
    <div class="heading-text">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<header id="navigation-bar " class="nav-header">
  <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/20x20" alt="logo-icon">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">How we work <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item2 active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item2 active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Account <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link nav-btn-link" href="#"><button class="nav-btn btn btn-outline-dark">View
                  Plans</button><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```